# Identifying contiguously repeating sub-sequence arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sequence

Suppose I have a problem where my sequence should look like this:

```
>>> np.repeat([1,2,3,4],6)
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4,
       4, 4])
```

But in reality it looks more like this, because of noise, corrupted sensors or whatever:

```
array([6, 1, 1, 6, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 8, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4])
```

values have been missed, or incorrectly registered.

Now I want to:

1. Find the number of contiguous sequences and its identifier (by this I mean that e.g. `1,1,1,1,1,1` is a sequence of length six with all values `1`).
2. All the contiguous sequences should have the same length, but because of noise and corrupted data this may not be present in the data. I also want to find the length of the contiguous sequence.
3. Finally, on a high level, I want to be able to tell if a sequence that I pass to my function has this structure (repeating contiguous sequence) -- basically some kind of test that returns `True` or `False` depending on the nature of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `medfilt` from `scipy` [`signal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.medfilt.html) module

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

org = np.array([6, 1, 1, 6, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 8, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4])

filt = signal.medfilt(org)

plt.plot(range(len(org)), org, label='orgiginal')
plt.plot(range(len(filt)), filt, label='filtered')
plt.legend()

print(filt)

sub_arrays = np.split(filt, np.where(np.diff(filt))[0]+1)
print(sub_arrays)
number_contiguous_sequences = len(sub_arrays)

for array in sub_arrays:
    print(len(array)) # gives 4, 7, 5, 6
```

filt:

```
[1. 1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4.]
```

sub_arrays:

```
[array([1., 1., 1., 1.]), array([2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.]), array([3., 3., 3., 3., 3.]), array([4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.])]
```

[image]